# How to handle dynamically changing xpath id?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am working on a LinkedIn scraping project. I use selenium and chrome driver. After login with my credentials, then the script will search for python programmers.

```
people = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ember5453"]/ul/li[1]/button')
people.click()
```

Above code is expected to choose people from (People, Company, Job, Content, Groups), but its not working. The problem is with the xpath id, it will change dynamically.

Comment: Post the code trials and elaborate on *didn't work*. What happened exactly?

Comment: Please view the `Tour` item in the help menu (question mark at the top right of the page) to learn about how to ask so that it fits the StackOverflow requirements.

Comment: can you clear what actually you want so people can help you out over here.

Answer (score 1):

The xpath that you are using contains some randomly generated number which gets changed on every page load, try using dynamic xpaths which don't have such id.

A simple solution would be to use the concept of textcontains, parent, child etc while xpath creation.

You can use `//input[@placeholder="Search"]` instead of `//*[@id="ember5453"]/ul/li[1]/button`.